# Peak Execution Memory in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Apache spark UI One of metrics at stage level is "Peak Execution Memory"? What this metrics indicating.

Answer (score 6):

**`Peak Execution memory`** refers to the memory used by internal data structures created during shuffles, aggregations and joins. The value of this accumulator should be approximately the sum of the peak sizes across all such data structures created in this task. For SQL jobs, this only tracks all unsafe operators, broadcast joins, and external sort.

You can get more insights about the same using [Tracking spark's memory usage](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12770224/Tracking%20Spark%20Memory%20Usage%20-%20Phase%201.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

The peak execution memory metric was introduced in SPARK-8735. That was before Tungsten was enabled by default, so it assumed that `spark.sql.unsafe.enabled` must be explicitly set to true.

Spark has many uses of memory: caching, shuffle, metadata etc. It is useful for users to be able to drill down on the internal memory allocation for memory-intensive operations like aggregations and joins. The goal is to do this for both tungsten and non-tungsten applications.

Have a look at as well [SPARK-10144](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10144)